# ClojureScript is throwing a syntax error on simple namespace definition

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm working to learn Clojure and Clojurescript; currently going through the book ***Living Clojure***.

I'm having trouble getting ClojureScript to compile ... I just put up the example as specified in the book:

```
(ns cheshire-cat.core)

(defn ^:export init []
  (js/alert "hi"))
```

I tried the book suggestion to run the compiler

`lein cljsbuild auto`

But I get this error:

```
Compiling ClojureScript.
Syntax error macroexpanding clojure.core/ns at (cljsbuild/crossover.clj:1:1).
import - failed: #{:refer-clojure} at: [:ns-clauses :refer-clojure :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-refer-clojure
import - failed: #{:require} at: [:ns-clauses :require :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-require
import - failed: #{:import} at: [:ns-clauses :import :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-import
import - failed: #{:use} at: [:ns-clauses :use :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-use
import - failed: #{:refer} at: [:ns-clauses :refer :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-refer
import - failed: #{:load} at: [:ns-clauses :load :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-load
import - failed: #{:gen-class} at: [:ns-clauses :gen-class :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-gen-class

Full report at:
/tmp/clojure-3119149998558661227.edn
```

Help please? I've been working with Clojure for a few weeks but just starting ClojureScript.

Comment: The error says that it's in `crossover.clj`, but the file that you show should be `src/cheshire_cat/core.cljs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue was fixed in here

https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild/commit/3d4d8d8f89f140e6b28aa8ce995c44743e4c6cf3

You should bump your cljsbuild to `1.1.8` or downgrade your clojure to 1.8.0